# LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, hyperlink

I have a problem with linking in VC++ 2010. When I compile in the debug mode it's ok, but in the release mode I regular receive the error "LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you cannot provide any details whatsoever then you'll need help from Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It began work as soon as I have changed "Whole program optimization" option from "Use Link Time Code Generation" to "Profile Guided Optimization-Instrument".

Comment: In VS 2017 you need to switch the **Whole Program Optimization** to **No** instead of **Yes**.

Comment: If you don't want to skip on Whole Program Optimization, a rebuild also works. It would be interesting to know what the reason for that error message is, which seems to appear from time to time.

Comment: Neither rebuild neither whole program optimization setting have any effect. I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error. The problem in my case was that I was "playing" with the configuration properties (Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General)

The 'Configuration Type' of the project was 'Dynamic Library (.dll)', but the 'Target Extension' was .lib instead of .dll.

Comment: That was my case. Thank you for indicating it.

Answer (score 1):

**April 2020 update**

Issue with MSBuild and Docker for Windows was fixed in MSBuild 16.5 ([source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/145618/msbuild-linkexe-hangs-inside-container.html?childToView=806109#comment-806109)), so if still seeing that - just update MSVS/MSBuild to the latest version

**Original answer**

```
Check for working C compiler: C:/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
......

LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage.FinalPhase
```

I was getting this error when I was running `cmake` in Docker for Windows inside **mounted** Docker volume. Solution is to copy the workspace to local Docker filesystem.

Comment: Ok, i'm also getting this strictly in docker mounted filesystem scenario.  Copying to workspace is not an option for our case, need to open issue.

Comment: Possibly fixed in 16.4  .  It looks like Microsoft found the root of the issue was a file api that was used by a pdb-related executable and simply doesn't work in docker: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/145618/msbuild-linkexe-hangs-inside-container.html?childToView=806109#comment-806109

Comment: @solvingJ from your link `Anyway, the fix is not in 16.4 yet. But it should have been included in early preview releases of 16.5.`

Comment: Agreed, the fix that happened in 16.4 was for mspdbsrv.exe (i believe).  The fix for link.exe might be in 16.5, but can't be sure because there's no installer for a preview release of build tools for 16.5 to install in docker.

Comment: @solvingJ checked today for the different project - seems fixed now indeed. Updated my answer, thank for the link!

Answer (score 1):

In vs2019 it works for me：
Project->Property pages->Optimization->Link Time Code Generation, change from "Use Link Time Code Generation" to "Profile Guided Optimization-Instrument"